# Estimating asymptotically a sum (proof check)

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics

I hope this question is appropriate for MathOverflow, if not please remove it.

I have the following problem which is taken from the paper "Sharp Conditional Bound for Moments of the Riemann Zeta Function" by Adam J. Harper [(pdf version)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.4618.pdf).

**Main Question**

> Let $\beta_i=\frac{20^{i-1}}{(\log\log T)^2}$ for all $i\geq 1$, $k\geq 1$ and $\mathcal{I}=1+\max\{i\mid \beta_i\leq e^{-1000k}\}$, then $$
> \sum_{j=1}^{\mathcal{I}-1}e^{-0.01k/\beta_j}\ll_k 1.
> $$

**How I tried to approach the problem**

I tried to estimate this sum using a modified version of a standard way of tackling sums (for example see equation 1.62 in the book 'Analytic Number Theory' by Iwaniec and Kowalski) in number theory.

**Lemma**

> Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ monotonic increasing, $f\geq 0$ and $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{N}\subset \mathbb{R}$ an increasing sequence of points such that $\min\{a_{j+1}-a_j\}\geq 1$. Then
> $$
> \sum_{j=1}^{N}f(a_j)\leq\int_{a_1}^{a_N+1}f(t)\,dt.
> $$

*Proof.*
By monotonicity of the function we have that for $1\leq j \leq N$
$$
f(a_j)\leq \int_{a_j}^{a_j+1}f(t)\,dt.
$$
Since by hypothesis we have $\min\{a_{j+1}-a_j\}\geq 1$, it follows that $a_j+1\leq a_{j+1}$ and therefore
$$
f(a_j)\leq \int_{a_j}^{a_j+1}f(t)\,dt\leq \int_{a_j}^{a_{j+1}}f(t)\,dt, \qquad\qquad \forall 1\leq j\leq N-1,
$$
hence
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \sum_{j=1}^{N}f(a_j)&=\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}f(a_j) + f(a_N)\leq\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\int_{a_j}^{a_{j+1}}f(t)\,dt+\int_{a_N}^{a_N+1}f(t)\,dt=\int_{a_1}^{a_N+1}f(t)\,dt
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
proving our claim.

---

We can now use the above lemma to estimate our sum under consideration. We have first to prove that the hypothesis of the lemma are verified. We take $f(x)=e^x$ which is clearly monotonic increasing, positive and $\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R})$. We then take $a_j=-0.01k/\beta_j$. This sequence is monotonically increasing since also $\{\beta_i\}$ is an increasing sequence. Moreover, using that $\beta_{j+1}=20\beta_j$, we have
\begin{split}
a_{j+1}-a_j&=-\frac{0.01k}{\beta_{j+1}}+\frac{0.01k}{\beta_j}\\
&=0.01k\left(-\frac{1}{\beta_{j+1}}+\frac{1}{\beta_j}\right)\\
&=0.01k\left(-\frac{1}{20\beta_j}+\frac{1}{\beta_j}\right)\\
&=0.01k\left(\frac{19}{20\beta_j}\right)\\
&\geq 0.01k\left(\frac{19}{20\beta_{\mathcal{I}-1}}\right)\\
&\geq 0.01k\frac{19}{20} e^{1000k}\\
&\geq \frac{0.019}{20}e^{1000}\\
&\geq 1
\end{split}
where we have used that $\beta_j\leq \beta_{\mathcal{I}-1}$ for all $j\leq \mathcal{I}-1$ and that $\beta_{\mathcal{I}-1}\leq e^{-1000k}$ which implies that $\frac{1}{\beta_{\mathcal{I}}}\geq e^{1000k}$.
We can therefore apply the lemma and we get
\begin{split}
\sum_{j=1}^{\mathcal{I}-1}e^{-0.01k/\beta_j}&\leq \int_{-0.01k/\beta_1}^{-0.01k/\beta_{\mathcal{I}-1}+1} e^x\,dx\\
&\leq \int_{-\infty}^1 e^x\,dx\\
&=e
\end{split}
where we have used that $-0.01k/\beta_j\leq 0$ for all $j$.
This concludes the proof of our main question.

Does it make sense or there is some mistake that I cannot spot?
My doubt is: do I need really $\beta_{\mathcal{I}−1}≤e^{−1000k}$ to prove it? I think I do not, at least this is what my proof seems to suggest if there are no mistakes.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: From $\beta_{\mathcal{I}-1}\leq e^{-1000k}$ it does not follow that $\frac{1}{\beta_{\mathcal{I}}}\geq e^{1000k}$. It only follows that $\frac{1}{\beta_{\mathcal{I}-1}}\geq e^{1000k}$, which is sufficient, however. This is because $j\leq\mathcal{I}-1$, hence in bounding $a_{j+1}-a_j$ one can use $\frac{19}{20\beta_{\mathcal{I}-1}}$ in place of $\frac{19}{20\beta_{\mathcal{I}}}$. Note that $\beta_{\mathcal{I}-1}\leq e^{-1000k}$ was used in this argument.

Comment: Well, one does not need $\beta_{\mathcal{I}-1}\leq e^{-1000k}$ for this argument, it suffices that $\beta_{\mathcal{I}-1}\leq 10^{-3}$, say. However, Harper needs that $\log(1/\beta_\mathcal{I})\geq 900k$ for deducing his (3.1). You are summing the right hand side of Harper's (3.1), but one also needs the validity of (3.1).

Comment: Sorry for the typo. You are right, to get something negative in the exponent multiplying $1/\beta_j$ we need to have$$\left(2k-\frac{\log(1/\beta_{j+1})}{420}\right)\leq 0$$
which implies that $\beta_{j+1}\leq e^{-840k}$.